# Sql-server-2008 client Access license

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

case 1 : i have one user makes 10 connection from single computer, maximum number of connection at a given time = 10, what is the number CAL i need here ?

case 2 : i have 10 users have access to only 1 computer, 10 user connect from single computer - maximum connection at any given time = 1, what is the number CAL i need here ?

case 3 : i have 10 users using 10 computers,  all 10 are making total of  5 connection maximum in any given time, what is the number of CAL i need here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: 1 CAL - the CAL is the CLIENT access license, this is one client. Many programs open more than one connection internally. Note: this only applies if the user is not something like a web server acting on direct behalf of third parties.

Case 2: 1 CAL IMHO. Licensing model: Server + Device CAL - the CAL is assigned to the computer.

Case 3: 10 CAL - either assigned to the users of the computers. COULD be 5 only, too - I am absolutely not sure. Normally, though you would buy 10 anyway, because the 5 user limit is not something a business "wants to enforce". How come you have only 5 ppeople ever use it at the same time? What you do if nr 6 needs access? This is an unusual business case.

More info: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing.aspx - especially the licensing FAQ linked from there.

Comment: what about the case 1 - as web server ?

Comment: Depends. Service access for other reasons than access (like your own web shop) - Internet connector license. Customer access for accessing the server (like you sell webspace) - you need a SPLA contract with per processor licensing, rented monthly, and a lot cheaper than buying the licenses.

Comment: Running a hosting business etc. is NOT legal with purchased licenses.